# Android hide Actionbar show only the tabs

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, appbar

I want to show the tabs on the top, and hide the actionbar.

[*Only the parts in the red rectangle, and hide the empty row above them.*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etEii.jpg)

I used these lines to hide the icon, and the title on the actionbar:

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

Any suggestions what to do to have only the tabs in my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hide it in the code. You may also need to remove onCreateOptionsMenu you are using that (For example).

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
      return true;
}
```

Also add the following line in on create.

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

Comment: Thank you! It helped me.

Answer (score 0):

In your **Manifest**:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
```

Comment: It didn't work for me. I tried the second solution, and it worked.